# When using nested while statements,does the outer while affect the inner while

Tags: php

I am pulling some data from mysql using php and mysqli and i am surprised this code works as it should.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$result = $mysqli->query("select subscriber_number from r4_subscriber_choices");
/*
500 Records Here
*/
$ac = 'acc';
$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
$n = $row['subscriber_number'];
  //echo $i++ . '   ' .$row['subscriber_number'] . '<br/>';
  $new_q = $mysqli->query("select text_message from incoming_sms where dest_msisdn = $n  and text_message like '%acc%'");
  while($row2 = $new_q->fetch_array()){
  echo $i++ . '   ' .$row2['text_message'] . '<br/>';
  }

}

$result->close()

?>
```

The outer while is looping 500 records while the inner loops 57.In my mind, i was expecting the inner loop to also loop 500 times too since its inside the outer loop which loops 500 times but only does 57.

Can someone kindly explain why this is so?.

Comment: do your queries directly in sql, and check, how many results it gives you back. It doesn't matter inner / outter loop, it depends on your recordsets of your results. Also, use $j in the inner, not the same as the outter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope it doesnt run 57 times. It runs as many times as the outer loop does. Only that your echo is inside the second loop which has rows only for 57 outer records. Try this

```
  while($row2 = $new_q->fetch_array()){
    // echo $i++ . '   ' .$row2['text_message'] . '<br/>';
  }
  echo $i++;
```

For all the rows of the outer loop where the inner query returns 0 rows, you don't see an `echo` because your `echo` only executes when the inner loop also has rows. That is exactly it. Try having a dummy echo outside your inner loop and you'll see that your inner query gets executed as many times.

[**A Quick Demonstration**](https://eval.in/216668)

Answer (score 0):

If there are 500 results in your first query then obviously your outer loop will iterate 500 time. You already got that. The inner loop loops for as many records are returned for your "inner query". That inner loop starts and stops at least as many times as the outer one.

For example. If there are 500 rows in the outer one and if there are 50 records in each of your 500 inner queries, then your inner loop will iterate 25000 times all together.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the second while doesn't have always results. If $new_q has no results or the query is invalid the echo in the second while is not executed.

Comment: this is not really an answer, more of a comment... perhaps is a guess. try to provide more information